# Solve : $p\vec x+\vec{x}(\vec{x}\cdot \vec{b})=\vec{a}\times \vec{b}+\vec{c}$.

Tags: vectors

**Prob:** Solve : $p\vec x+\vec{x}(\vec{x}\cdot \vec{b})=\vec{a}\times \vec{b}+\vec{c}$.

I could not understand how to calculate it to solve the equation for $\vec x$.

Comment: Are $\lambda x$ and $x\lambda$ the same thing?

Comment: @AlvinLepik Here $p$ is  scalar, $\vec x$ is vector so, $p\vec x=\vec x p$

Comment: Calling $\vec d = \vec a\times\vec b +\vec c$ we have $$ \vec x = -\vec d \frac{p+2\sqrt{\vec b\cdot\vec d + p^2}}{2\vec b\cdot\vec d}$$ or $$ \vec x = \vec d\frac{2}{p+2\sqrt{\vec b\cdot\vec d + p^2}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First multiply by $b$ and notice that $(a\times b)\cdot b=0$.  You'll get a quadratic equation for $x\cdot b$. Plug the solution in the original equation and solve for $x$.

Comment: @MH Thank you very much. Your hint helped me to solve this problem. Done